# DG834G V3 Custom Firmware

Tags: router, firmware

Hopefully someone has configured this before - I'm in the process of flashing the DGTeam custom firmware for the Netgear DG834G V3 router (my spare one!) but now it's done, I've no idea what IP the router is on and can't find it on the net. Does anyone know how to find out, or has done this before?

I've tried all the obvious IPs on the 192.168.x.x range, but it could be anything, and isn't giving out DHCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed the DGTeam site has been down a while. However, I found a mirror site, offering the firmware files for the Netgear DG834G V3 router. The site does mention a warning not to use firmware revisions above 1018, else they will brick your router. Whether this is accurate I do not know.

The mirror site offers revisions 0849 for your router but why not go straight to the Netgear site and use OEM firmware.

The mirror site if interested is http://www.dgteam-mirror.talktalk.net/Home.html

An awful thought suggests you may not be able to re-flash the device if you cannot connect via its standard IP which is (was) 192.168.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that a router not giving out DHCP addresses could indicate a problem. I would suggest you either reset the settings on the router (which should change it to `192.168.1.1`, which is the default DGTeam Router IP Address, and it should also issue DHCP addresses), or in the worst case, use the DGTeam Recovery Tool, and perhaps lookup via the command line what address you have.

On Windows, you can go to Start->Accessories->Command Prompt and type `IPCONFIG` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. On *nix systems, drop down to the command line and type `ifconfig` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>